# Can I join an arbitrary number of nouns to make them act like adjectives?

Tags: nouns, attributive-nouns, compound-nouns

I always thought that I can join as many nouns as I want together and in fact make all of them play the role of adjectives except the last one. But the other day I was told that there is no such rule. However I can provide many examples:

- a Michael Bay film
- repetitive strain injury
- blue-collar worker
- maternity leave
- air pollution
- noise pollution
- water pollution

These are correct collocations, aren't they? Certainly I can "A film of Michael Bay", but "a Michael Bay film" seems even more natural for me.
Also we have air pollution, noise pollution, water pollution, but not environment pollution. Environmental pollution. Am I right? Can I say environment pollution? If no, why? And yet if there is such a rule that describes why I can say air pollution instead of pollution of air, how does it called?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "an arbitrary number of nouns".  Do you mean "add many nouns one after the other so they all act as adjectives" or "use any arbitrary noun as an adjective"?  You can certainly do the first; you could refer to a **car door handle button**, for example.

Comment: Sure - you *can* say ***environment pollution***. But that's [one of those cases](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+environment+pollution%2Cof+environmental+pollution&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20environment%20pollution%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20environmental%20pollution%3B%2Cc0) where we usually choose to use the dedicated adjectival form ***environmental pollution***. And English doesn't actually *have* an adjective meaning "of Michael Bay", but quite why we don't rail against ***airy pollution*** isn't that obvious to me.

Comment: @stangdon You are only half way there: Ford car door handle button replacement cost inflation estimate

Comment: @stangdon; But don't forget it should be a "useful big round broken old red spotted Chinese steel car door handle button"

Comment: @stangdon yes. The first one. "add many nouns one after the other so they all act as adjectives"

Comment: @FumbleFingers so. Did you just say that I may say "airy polution" insted of "air pollution"? Books Ngram viewer doesn't even show this collocation. I also found the following definition of "airy":
"not treating something as serious". Maybe airy pollution has a completely different meaning in comparison to air pollution?

Comment: @RonaldSole brilliant examples guys. Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, but they don't 'act as adjectives'. They are nouns (more precisely 'nominals') functioning as attributive **modifiers**.

Comment: @BillJ The trouble I have with your answers is that I'd believe you equally if you said they were retributive amplfiers. I don't think that your books had been written when I was studying English.

Comment: @BillJ Not intended as a complaint. Just a reflection!

Comment: I certainly did ***not*** just say that you may say "airy polution" insted of "air pollution"! Or at least, that's not what I ***meant***. I can only apologise because I didn't stop to think that my phrasing there might be misunderstood by people who aren't ***very*** familiar with English. When I said we don't rail (complain) about "airy pollution", I meant that ***nobody ever uses the term "airy pollution"*** (even though *logically*, one might think that since we nearly always use explicitly adverbial ***environmental** pollution*, we "should" perhaps do the same with adverbial ***airy***).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the rules of English grammar, you can make infinitely long sequences of noun adjuncts.

Your examples are idiomatic, and could even be lengthened by adding more attributive nouns:

- a Michael Bay film festival
- a Michael Bay film watching party
- a Michael Bay blockbuster film watching party
- a Michael Bay blockbuster film watching party analysis

As you can probably see, when the phrases get longer, they're more likely to be misunderstood.  In that last example, you have to read eight words before you discover what kind of activity is being described (an analysis, not a party, or a film, or a film maker).

While the language's grammar permits such phrases, they tend to be rare because there are usually better ways of conveying the same information.  For example, this is a headline that was published by BBC News: "Dawlish pub car park cliff plunge man rescued."  That sentences uses six nouns that all modify "man."  Newspapers like this kind of phrasing because it's compact, but for normal speech, it would be much preferred to say, "Emergency medical technicians **rescued** a **man** whose **car** **plunge**d off of the **cliff** at the edge of a **Dawlish pub**'s **parking lot**."

Knowing the "rule" - that you can chain together attributive nouns - is helpful, but whatever rule exists cannot tell you whether a specific attributive noun chain is idiomatic. As we've seen, length is one consideration, but there's no rule about that - often times a single attributive noun is less idiomatic than the adjectival version.  For example, "spine surgery" is more common than "spinal surgery," but "spine cord" is so uncommon, it will sound wrong (it's "spinal cord").

Unfortunately, the only way to know which phrasing is "correct" is to listen to and read a lot of English.

Comment: Noun adjunct or attributive nouns, that is the name of the grammar construction that I've been casting about for! And thank you for explaining this "spine surgery"/"spinal cord".

Comment: The six nouns in "Dawlish pub car park cliff plunge" don't _individually_ modify "man". There are several layers of modification involved: first "plunge" is modified by "cliff" to form the nominal "cliff plunge". Similarly, "car park" forms a nominal which is modified by the nominal "Dawlish pub" to give the nominal “Dawlish pub car park”. The nominal "Dawlish pub car park” then modifies “cliff plunge" and finally the upper nominal “Dawlish pub car park cliff plunge” modifies “man”.  I think!!